# Model for flutter analysis of Aerofoil

Tags: aerodynamics

Why is a aerofoil modeled by attached torsional and linear spring in a  wing flutter analysis.The model does not even satisfy the boundary condition of zero displacement of wing at point of attachment to fuselage. I am considering the pitch plunge model as shown in figure.[image]

Answer (score 3):

Because what you are simulating is not a wing, but an aerofoil at an arbitrary $y$ station along the wing. 
The linear spring simulates the wing bending and the torsional one its torsion about the elastic axis. The constants would of course be of the type $k_{e}=f(y)$.

Comment: how does this help us analyse a real world airplane flutter case?

Comment: you can adjust the constants of those springs to study a specific wing section, which is good enough for the level this preliminary study. More importantly, it already exhibits some of the crucial properties of flutter, like torsional divergence above a certain $U_{\infty}$. Though you should really refine your question, this is just my offhand remark to your initial overly broad query.